# How to use ReactiveQuerydslPredicateExecutor with spring webflux

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, querydsl

I'm trying to use `ReactiveQuerydslPredicateExecutor` with spring webflux, using Mysql database and r2dbc. Repository extending `ReactiveSortingRepository` works perfectly.

However if I extend `ReactiveQuerydslPredicateExecutor` as well, then it won't compile. I'm enabling the r2dbc with `EnableR2dbcRepositories`. Back in the day before the reactive packages, one had to change the base package of "EnableJPARepositories" to the related "Q" one. However I can't find anything here, and it says there is no "findAll method".

The code:

```
@Table("user")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@QueryEntity
public class User {

    @Id
    Long id;

    String name;

    String email;
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveSortingRepository<User, Long>, ReactiveQuerydslPredicateExecutor<User> {
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = ReactiveCrudRepository.class)
public class AppConfig {
}
```

The error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type User!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:311) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:276) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:82) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:252) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.query.PartTreeR2dbcQuery.<init>(PartTreeR2dbcQuery.java:66) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar:1.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
```

*** EDIT: ***

my database connection (in application.properties):

```
spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testdb
spring.r2dbc.username=root
spring.r2dbc.password=
```

my pom.xml: (I'm using the newest version of everything, exclusions are there, because version conflicts of the same package. Older ones are excluded.)

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jasync-sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasync-r2dbc-mysql</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>r2dbc-spi</artifactId>
                    <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-common</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-sql-spring</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: we need more code, how do you set up your database connection, and your pom.xml

Comment: Added both. This is my full pom xml, except the boilerplate artifactId, groupId.

Comment: Can you please motivate all the exclusions in the pom?

Comment: What do you mean motivate? Explain? Everything that is excluded, is included in the other package with a higher version number.

Comment: In `UserRepository` the `@Repository` annotation won't do anything because there's no singleton to put into the spring context.

Answer (score 2):

There is no repository such as `SimpleR2dbcRepository` implements  `ReactiveQuerydslPredicateExecutor`.

In JPA, there is `QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor` implements `QuerydslPredicateExecutor`.

So if your repository implements `QuerydslPredicateExecutor`, Spring Data JPA can create a proxy to use methods of `SimpleJpaRepository` and `QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor` for your repository.

Querydsl has not supported r2dbc yet.